# How to separate a tuple with 2 parts into separate lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append, tuples

So I have a tuple that has two lists in it:

```
x = (['a', 's', 'd'], ['1', '2', '3'])
```

How do I make it into two lists? Right now my code basically looks like:

```
list1.append(x[1])
list1.append(x[2])
list1.append(x[3])
```

But I can't add the other 3 items into a separate list with indexes 4, 5 and 6:

```
list2.append(x[4])
list2.append(x[5])      -results in an error
list2.append(x[6])
```

How can I do the above to make a list2?

Comment: `list1, list2 = x`? Note that Python indices are **zero-based**, by the way.

Comment: `list1.append(x[2])` will already throw an error, because `x` only has indices `0` and `1`.

Comment: @kasramvd: How are this question and that dupe target related?

Comment: It's very clear. In both questions OP wants to assign the items of an iterable to separate variables. I'm wonder that why you reopened the question. I'm sure that it's not because of your answer to question but I would be appreciate if you tell the the reason.

Comment: @Kasramvd: I've responded to you in the Python chat room.

Comment: @Kasramvd: but the tldr version is: this question is not about assigning dynamically.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Your tuple has only two elements. Just reference those directly:

```
list1 = x[0]
list2 = x[1]
```

or

```
list1, list2 = x
```

This creates *additional references* to the two lists contained in `x`, *not copies*. If you need *new* list objects with the same contents, create copies:

```
list1, list2 = x[0][:], x[1][:]
```

See [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new at this so I automatically tried appending with indexes 1, 2 and 3, which gave me the correct answer for list1, but didn't work for list2

Comment: @S.Martin: but you don't *have* and index `2` in your tuple, as defined in the question. If those indices worked, then `x` is a different object and you asked the wrong question.